# Cheap 500mV reference

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

For a project, I need a 500mV reference.

Some requirements:

1. Relatively low cost.
2. Small size. Preferably surface mount.
3. Supply from 4.8V to 25V.
4. Accuracy ±5% or better
5. Stable over voltage (that is, it doesn't change that much with a different supply.)

I could use a diode drop but it does not satisfy condition 5, being stable over voltage.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but you seem to know all of the relevant characteristics and have a complete understanding of what you need, so why not go to Digikey or Mouser and use the search feature to drill down and find what you need?  There's a whole subcategory for voltage references that I found easily and I used your criteria I came up with the same answer in less than 5 minutes.  Doing it this way seems roundabout and slow.

Comment: I just wanted people's opinions on the best way to approach it. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about this 
http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/Data_Sheets/ADR130.pdf
cheap from digikey circa $2 for single units, wide input voltage range (2-18 V) stable output over temperature a wide temperature range of 50 ppm per degree C, and +/- 0.7% initial accuracy, and small size TSOT package.

Use a voltage divider on the input side to drop your 4.8 V - 25 V to 2.4 to 12.5V which is suitable.

I think that is a tick in every box :)